# Drupal UR mutual relationship doesn't show for both users

Tags: drupal-7, relationships

I'm working with Drupal 7 User Relationships and I'm having some problems with mutual relationships.

Example:

User A request B for mutual relationship
B approves relationship with A

Then we look in B profile under relationships we see that B has relationship with A.
But then we look in A profile under relationships we see that it doesn't have any relationship with B. If A would go to B user profile A could request for relationship again.

I was expecting that mutual relationship would be shown on both profiles after it was approved but it isn't. What can I do so that it would show the relationship on A and B profiles not only on B as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I finally found that there is a patch for this problem. You can find it here http://drupal.org/node/1211060#comment-5105036